# RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (1, 1, 512), got (1, 128, 512) for LSTM pytorch

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I trained the LSTM with a batch size of 128 and during testing my batch size is 1, why do I get this error? I'm suppose to initialize the hidden size when doing testing?

Here is the code that i'm using, I initialize the hidden state **init_hidden** function as *(number_of_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)* since *batch_first=True*

```
class ImageLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,  n_inputs:int=49, 
                    n_outputs:int=4096, 
                    n_hidden:int=256, 
                    n_layers:int=1, 
                    bidirectional:bool=False):
    """
    Takes a 1D flatten images.
    """
    super(ImageLSTM, self).__init__()
    self.n_inputs   = n_inputs
    self.n_hidden   = n_hidden
    self.n_outputs  = n_outputs
    self.n_layers   = n_layers
    self.bidirectional = bidirectional
    self.lstm       = nn.LSTM(  input_size=self.n_inputs, 
                                hidden_size=self.n_hidden, 
                                num_layers=self.n_layers, 
                                dropout  = 0.5 if self.n_layers>1 else 0,
                                bidirectional=self.bidirectional,
                                batch_first=True)
    if (self.bidirectional):
        self.FC         = nn.Sequential(
                                        nn.Linear(self.n_hidden*2, self.n_outputs),
                                        nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
                                        nn.Sigmoid()
                                            )

    else:
        self.FC         = nn.Sequential(
                                        nn.Linear(self.n_hidden, self.n_outputs),
                                        # nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
                                        nn.Sigmoid()
                                        )

    
def init_hidden(self, batch_size, device=None): # input 4D tensor: (batch size, channels, width, height)
    # initialize the hidden and cell state to zero
    # vectors:(number of layer, batch size, number of hidden nodes)
    if (self.bidirectional):
        h0 = torch.zeros(2*self.n_layers,  batch_size, self.n_hidden)
        c0 = torch.zeros(2*self.n_layers,  batch_size, self.n_hidden)
    else:
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.n_layers,  batch_size, self.n_hidden)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.n_layers,  batch_size, self.n_hidden)

    if device is not None:
        h0 = h0.to(device)
        c0 = c0.to(device)
    self.hidden = (h0,c0)

def forward(self, X): # X: tensor of shape (batch_size, channels, width, height)
    # forward propagate LSTM
    lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(X, self.hidden) # lstm_out: tensor of shape (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_size)
    # Decode the hidden state of the last time step 
    out = self.FC(lstm_out[:, -1, :])
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

please edit your post and add code. How did you initialize the hidden-state? What does you model look like.

`hidden[0]` is not your hidden-size, its the hidden-state of the lstm. The shape of the hidden-state has to be initialized like this:

```py
hidden = ( torch.zeros((batch_size, layers, hidden_size)), torch.zeros((layers, batch_size, hidden_size)) )
```

You seem to have done this correctly. But the error tells you that you gave a batch of size 1 (because as you said you want to test with only one sample) but the hidden-state is initialized with batch-size=128.

So I guess (please add code) that you hard-coded that the batch-size = 128. Dont do that. Since you have to reinitialize the hidden-state every forward pass you can do this:

```py
...

def forward(self, x):
    batch_size = x.shape[0]
    hidden = (torch.zeros(self.layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device=device), torch.zeros(self.layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device=device))

    output, hidden = lstm(x, hidden)
    
    # then do what every you want with the output
```

I guess that this is what causes this error but please post your code, too!